# Problems in receiving fragmented UDP packets in C

Tags: c, udp

I'm using 2 different C programs to received fragmented  packets, one using a raw socket defined as following:

```
_socket0 = socket( PF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, htons(ETH_P_ALL) );
```

one using an UDP socket defined as following:

```
_socket0=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
```

The first one works fine, the second one doesn't work, I'm not able to see nothings.
Anyone can tell me the reason?

Answer (score 0):

A fragment of an UDP packet is not a UDP packet, so it won't be passed to a UDP socket. UDP sockets are for reading/writing whole UDP packets, not IP packets carrying fragments of one.

Comment: This is clear but for what I know when a PC receive fragmented packets before send the packets to the new layer (teh UDP layer) it recombine the fragments to obtain a singole bigger packets. So probably the problem is why the PC doesn't recombine the packet.

Comment: In reality first of all I don't understand why I'm not able to receive also single UDP packet, this colud be the original problem